# Accessing dynamically populated form data uisng new FormData(this)

Tags: jquery

I am populating values of a form using JQuery as shown below.

```
 form.find("input[name=" + test1 + "]").val("test1");
 form.find("input[name=" + test2 + "]").val("test2");
```

On submit of the form, if i use the below code

```
var formData = $(this).serialize();
```

I can get the form field values correctly.

But if I use,

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
```

Form field values are empty.

As i have to upload a file, i have to use FormData instead of serialize.
How can we access dynamically populated form data using the FormData?

Comment: You cannot easily retrieve the information from a `FormData` object in JS as it's encoded binary data. Why would you need to, though? All the information that's put in to the FormData is available in the DOM in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to see the data in a FormData object in the console without making the XHR request. so Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#class_name').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //enter code here
    var formdata = new FormData(this);

    console.log(formdata);
  });
});
```